# In System monitor, what is the difference between Kill Process and End Process?

Tags: process, system-monitor

When I want to kill a process via System Monitor I am presented with 2 quick ways, Kill Process and End Process. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the System Monitor manual, you should normally use "End Process", and only if that fails use "Kill Process":

> You usually terminate a process only if you cannot end the process
>   normally as described in To End a Process.

On a technical level this makes me think that End Process sends a SIGQUIT, which allows the process to trap and perform cleanup if needed, but if that fails, Kill Process should send a SIGKILL which should violently terminate the process, without chance of recovery. Use sparingly!

Comment: SIGTERM is the "polite" way to close a program, which is what "End Process" sends. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

Comment: So is it `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT`?

Answer (score 25):

I was curious too, so I just browsed through the source code and found the below in [application.cpp](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/gnome-system-monitor/trunk/view/head:/src/application.cpp#L410). There is more to this code but I think these correlate to the options, at least for System Monitor 3.8.2.1 through 3.19.3:

- **Stop Process = SIGSTOP** (*pause signal*, let's you continue later with SIGCONT, does not kill process)
- **End Process = SIGTERM**  (*termination signal*, the right way, the application can intercept this signal and intiate shutdown tasks such as temp file cleanup)
- **Kill Process = SIGKILL** (*kill signal*, extreme, only use if SIGTERM doesn't work, won't intiate shutdown tasks)

See [this question on Quora about SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL and SIGSTOP signals](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-SIGINT-and-SIGTERM-signals-in-Linux) for a good explanation on all of the kill/quit/shutdown signals and their differences.

[image: Source code highlight]