# Kinder / gentler / subtler equivalent alternative to killall (e.g. "endall")?

Tags: command-line, process, kill, killall

How do I end all processes with the same name in a more gentle way than `killall` does? I don't want to interrupt the processes, but leave them time to properly quit.

---

See also:

[How do I kill processes in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu)

[In System monitor, what is the difference between Kill Process and End Process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124927/in-system-monitor-what-is-the-difference-between-kill-process-and-end-process)

[Why does killall (sometimes?) needs to be applied twice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676673/why-does-killall-sometimes-needs-to-be-applied-twice)

<sub>[tl;dr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals#comment4351902_4047975)</sub>

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Pilot6 *re-phrased:* what's a "softer" alternative to killall ?

Comment: What is "softer"?

Comment: @Pilot6 "softer" in the sense of [System Monitor's "End" vs "Kill"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124927/in-system-monitor-what-is-the-difference-between-kill-process-and-end-process)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## 1. `killall` already nice (SIGTERM)

`killall` by default sends `SIGTERM`. This is *already* the nice approach that leaves applications the chance to clean up after themselves. The "go die already, right now!" approach is to send a `SIGKILL` signal, which requires specifying that as an option to `killall`. From [The GNU C Library: Termination Signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html):

> Macro: *int* **SIGTERM**
>
> [...] It is the normal way to ***politely*** ask a program to terminate.

---

## 2. System Monitor's "End process" equally nice (SIGTERM, too)

You link to a question about GNOME System Monitor. That does use `SIGTERM` for its "End process" action too (and I realise I am contradicting the answer to that question). You can find it in the source code to verify yourself:

[data/menus.ui](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/blob/master/data/menus.ui):

```
<item>
  <attribute name="label" translatable="yes">_End</attribute>
  <attribute name="action">win.send-signal-end</attribute>
  <attribute name="accel">&lt;Primary&gt;e</attribute>
  <attribute name="target" type="i">15</attribute>
</item>
```

The 15 here is the signal number. Signal 15 is `SIGTERM`. And System Monitor has used `SIGTERM` well before that other question was asked and answered.

---

#### Technical addendum (in response to a comment)

<sub>Looking through the Github representation of `git blame`, here are the changes that have been made to how the signals are spelt out in the source code of GNOME System Monitor:</sub>

<sub>[383007f2](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/commit/383007f2fa3a0ede8524fe83f402279c09a242b9) 24 Jul 2013 Replaced duplicated code for sending signals with GAction parameters

[0e766b2d](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/commit/0e766b2dbbdb3484655e100a19b13c2d4cd1170f) 18 Jul 2013 Port process popup menu to GAction

[97674c79](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/commit/97674c7940e819bef14c8a98bd181cbb5a604226) 3 Oct 2012 Get rid of ProcData structure

[38c5296c](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/commit/38c5296cdda1afab6cb7cfe6bcafb991a665ebc9) 3 Jul 2011 Make indentation uniform across source files.</sub>

<sub>None of these changed from `SIGQUIT` to `SIGTERM`, and that last one was from before the linked question was asked.</sub>

Comment: +1 for referring to source code ! ( +2 for contradicting "conventional wisdom", as it were ;)

Comment: Well, before stating that you are contradicting the answer: did you check that all *versions* of the source code use `15`? It may have been changed at some point so the old answer *could* be 100% right with respect to an old version.

Comment: @Bakuriu I do contradict that answer either way, but fair point, I will try to remember to check that next time I can.

Comment: @Bakuriu in the source git tree, `git grep 'SIGQUIT'` doesn't reveal anything. Nothing related to signals is found for `git grep '>3<'` either. I conclude that most likely gnome-system-monitor has never used `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: @Ruslan `git grep` only searches the current tree, not the whole history. I used `git blame` (actually the Github equivalent) to dig a bit deeper, but still nothing.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @hvd is basically correct. To back that up even more, the `init` process will first send `SIGTERM` to processes when your are shutting down your computer, then after a delay will send `SIGKILL` if they have not already exited. Processes can't handle/ignore `SIGKILL`.

To give a bit more detail though, the real answer is that you have no way of knowing for sure that the program handles it. `SIGTERM` is the most usual signal to use for politely asking a program to quit, but all signal handling depends on the program doing something with the signal.

To put it a different way, based on the other answers, if you had a program written by @Jos or by @AlexGreg then they would presumably be handling `SIGQUIT` but possibly not `SIGTERM`, and hence sending `SIGTERM` would be less "soft" than `SIGQUIT`.

I've written some code so you can play around with it yourself. Save the below as `signal-test.c`, then compile with

```
gcc -o signal-test signal-test.c
```

You can then run it `./signal-test`, and see what happens when you send different signals with `killall -s <signal>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int flag = 0;

void handle_signal(int s)
{
    flag = s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal);
    signal(SIGQUIT, handle_signal);

    while(flag == 0){
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("flag is %d\n", flag);
    return flag;
}
```

As it stands, the code handles both SIGTERM and SIGQUIT gracefully. You could try commenting out the lines `signal(SIG...` (using a `//` at the start of the line) to remove the signal handler, then run and send the signals again. You should be able to see these different outputs:

```
$ ./signal-test
Terminated

$ ./signal-test
Quit (core dumped)

$ ./signal-test
flag is 15

$ ./signal-test
flag is 3
```

depending on whether you handle the signals or not.

You could also try ignoring the signals:

```
signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
```

If you do that then sending `SIGTERM` will do nothing, you'll have to use `SIGKILL` to end the process.

More details in `man 7 signal`. Note that using `signal()` in this way is considered non-portable - it's lots easier than the alternative though!

One other minor footnote - on Solaris `killall` attempts to kill all processes. All of them. If you run it as root then you may be surprised :)

Comment: This is one of the reasons I prefer `pkill`. The other reason is that it pairs with `pgrep`, which makes it easier to check exactly what processes will be killed, and which itself has better matching semantics than `ps | grep`.

Answer (score 1):

"End all" would be `killall -s SIGQUIT [process name]`. If you want a fancy solution, define `alias endall='killall -s SIGQUIT'`.

Comment: `SIGQUIT` is like making the process `abort(3)`: it dumps core and then kills the process. This is in no way nicer/gentler/kinder than `SIGTERM` which is default for `killall`.

Comment: For a process that handles signals, `SIGQUIT` (or even better, `SIGINT`) might be treated more 'softly' than `SIGTERM`, but this is up to the application. Unhandled, any of them cause immediate termination.

Comment: This is a great idea, if you like cleaning up core files all over your disk.

Comment: I'd like to re-iterate @R..'s point: `Unhandled, any of them cause immediate termination.` Signals are a convention on the application's end. What they actually *do* is up to the application, though the kernel does treat them a bit differently.

Comment: @Qix: One thing that varies per signal is whether it creates a core file or not on the default action (when not handled by the application). It's probably preferable to use signals that don't generate core files.

Comment: @R.. agreed, though in the context of *which signal causes the program the least amount of stress* is a moot point if the program doesn't handle *any* signal to begin with.

Comment: It's worth noting that ubuntu sets the core file size limit to 0 by default, so SIGQUIT won't actually produce a core file (if unhandled) unless you modify the limit.