# Kill terminal process?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install ruby virtual machine by running commands from terminal.While installing rails some error occurs and terminal got stuck up.What should be the action in the specified case.I tried ctrl+esc, esc, ../ etc like command prompt from windows.But it doesn't work.What is the proper way to end the process without closing the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Try these keyboard shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>

Comment: CTRL+C send a SIGINT to the process, which is can handle as it likes. It's very much a common and reasonable way to end a process.

Comment: @AndersOlsson You're absolutely right. I got confused myself in the middle of two answers suggesting to terminate a process with SIGKILL (one of which you can't see because it has been deleted), my bad.

Comment: Ctrl+Z also suspends it: https://askubuntu.com/a/510816/1088830

Answer (score -3):

use ps or top to fınd out PID(proces ıd) and use kill -9 PID

Comment: `kill -9` is not the proper way to terminate a process, leaves everything in a messy state and resources allocated by the process around. You should first try at least `kill -15`.

Comment: so whats meanıng of  -15

Comment: `kill -9` sends a SIGKILL signal, `kill -15` sends a SIGTERM signal. The first one is not ignorable / handable by the process, which is shut down by the kernel instantly (i.e. whatever the process was doing it's interrupted half-way, and in the best case the process will just leave temporary files around); the second one is ignorable / handable by the process, which has the chance to clean up allocated resources and to terminate gracefully (i.e. it does basically what's outlined in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/676666/380067))